# Test inheriting classes in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, inheritance

I have just learned unittest in python, and I would like to know if there is a way to execute tests on classes that inherit from a super class. For example, if you have :

```
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

class C(A):
    pass
```

Is it possible to run a test for all the classes that inherit from A (so B and C)?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Do you mean execute the same test suite on three different (but related) classes? Look into parameterisation, which you may find easier in `py.test` in `unittest`.

Comment: Yes, tahnk you, that is a bit of that, and do you know how to find all the classes that inherit A?

Comment: `A.__subclasses__`